# Why can we interpret this latency vs. array size graph like this?

Tags: caching, gpu

I was Googling around and came upon [this paper](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~moshovos/CUDA08/arx/microbenchmark_report.pdf) on gauging various data on the cache of a graphics processing unit. The paper has this read latency vs. array size graph that looks like a step function.

[image]

Apparently, from this graph, we can tell that the cache size is 2048B (where the steps begin), the line size is the width of a single step, and the "way size" (whatever that is) is the width of the whole section of steps (2560B - 2048B).

That's really neat and makes it convenient to determine the structure of a cache, which I don't believe is usually documented for GPUs. However, I am wondering where these interpretations stem from. What's the justification / logic behind them?

Comment: If you put more than 2048B into the cache and try and retrieve the data, you will get a cache miss, which will increase the latency.  Further increases further increase the cache misses and therefore the latency.

Comment: A set-associate scheme works by dividing the cache SRAM into equal
sections (2 or 4 sections typically) called cache ways. The cache page size is equal to the size of
the cache way. Each cache way is treated like a small direct mapped cache.  http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/papers/cache6.pdf

Comment: If we put more than the cache size into the cache, why is anything beyond 2048B relevant to the cache any more? How do we know that the width of a step for instance is the cache line size if the steps are beyond the size of the cache (and thereby no longer relevant to the cache)?

Comment: Well, you won't get a step at all unless you exceed the cache size, becaues you won't get a cache miss.